# Found PVC while digging, what is the purpose of the pipe I hit?

Tags: wiring, pvc, underground

So I didn't call before I started digging because I was replacing an existing fence and I just made the assumption there would be any issue in moving the post hole a little bit. As luck would have it I hit two different types of pipes when digging the new holes. Any ideas on fixes for this or what this even is?

Not the sprinkler line as when i turned on the sprinklers no leaking occurred. Nothing came leaking out of either one and getting a current clamp tomorrow to see if the black one is electrical.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A current clamp won't tell you if it's electrical, as you need to clamp a single conductor. The two wires together cancel each other out. What you need is a non-contact voltage sensor, but be aware that will only tell you if it's currently hot (eg: if it's for a light, it might be off but still active).

Comment: It would help a lot to know what facilities are on the property, i.e. which might have such services going to them.  If you could say 'there's a 60A subpanel in my barn' or "we added q bathroom in the pool house" etc.  also, how deep did you dig?

Comment: Both things were about 1' deep and i have no facilities on the property aside from sprinkler system.

Comment: Given the depth, the first one looks like drainage and the second one looks like low pressure irrigation for gardens/plants (but that's just a huge guess).

Comment: To me both pics look irrigation related.  When you turned on irrigation did you test all stations/zones?   The first looks like 2 irrigation pipes that were pulled together, are those pipes about 1" diameter?  The black does look like a wire but I'm guessing it's irrigation control multi-conductor wire.  A non-contact voltage detector won't help in that case, what is the diameter here?  Can you spot and writing on the outside?

Comment: By the way, "call before you dig" only locates utilities buried, not things like irrigation systems.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. When I tested all the zones nothing leaked. Both pipes are 1" in diameter. I have this tool and will check if its hot http://www.kleintools.com/catalog/electrical-testers/non-contact-voltage-tester I dug up several feet of the black pipe and couldn't find writing of any kind. I also dug up one of my sprinkler lines because I was curious and it was only 3/4". There is no scale inside the white pipe almost like it's never used. I'll cut out that section and replace it just in case. I'll report back this evening if the black line was power.

Comment: I suspect what's inside the black sheath is 13 conductors for irrigation control.  (Google "multi conductor irrigation wire" and click images).  If that's the case then your non-contact voltage detector won't find "hot" because irrigation is 24volt and that detector min voltage is 50 according to the specs (even if it did detect 24v the voltage detection would be inconclusive because once a color say blue reaches its valve it's still in the cable after that but no longer connected).

Comment: That could also be RG11 for a long cable TV drop, also your non-contact voltage detector won't detect anything there.

Comment: The black cable/pipe is an inch in diameter the data sheets on the multi conductor irrigation wire pointed to being a 1/4" outer diameter.

Comment: If these were right on the fence line...could they be your neighbors sprinkler system? The black one looks like a garden feed for lower pressure drip type lines, or a smaller water line off the main line. My yard had a few of the black thinner pipes coming from the main line out to where the sprinklers were buried. It is more flexible and easier to move the sprinklers around.

Comment: Confirmed. The black line was my sprinkler line just wasn't damaged enough to leak. I went ahead and replaced the damaged portion just in case. No idea what the white pvc pipe is/was but replaced it just incase too. Now i encountered concrete not sure how far it goes... this is quite the adventure.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is the two pvc are abandoned irrigation given the size and thickness. The black is definitely for a drip system and the wire is most likely low voltage landscape lighting. Keep in mind all any of us can do is tell you what those items were intended For by the mfg. I have seen many a product abused and misused so without testing one cannot be sure. But given the material, location, depth, and proximity odds are very high that one or more of us nailed it. Not quite as good as you did though.